# GDL not found after installing with homebrew

Tags: installation, homebrew, gnu, gdl

I used brew install GDL. The install was completed, but once I try to use GDL, it says " command not found: gdl".

I used "which gdl", but still can't be located. I tried reinstalling GDL via brew, but same error.

I tried changing the directory to the folder where brew installed GDL, but no luck either.

I looked through my other compilers and those are saved into bin, while GDL is not (if that's relevant at this point).

Anything will help!

Answer (score 0):

If the intention was to install GNU Data Language, please try installing gnudatalanguage from homebrew-science: https://github.com/brewsci/homebrew-science/blob/master/Formula/gnudatalanguage.rb